# Security Error Exception occurs whenever I tries to convert simple image source to data URL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, security

I am working on a mobile application advertisement project so I need banner or thumbnail of application image to be made. The list of applications is coming live from google play and apple store. So my website is making use of other outbound domains and not local domains.

I am using HTML 5 canvas element to manage runtime functionality and to save entire canvas as an image. What I need to do is to make default banner(after saving canvas) based on user's color preference and font color etc.

My canvas coding is given below :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" name="myCanvas" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid;margin-top: 25px;margin-left: 73px;margin-bottom: 12px;background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4e54,  #4c4e54);"></canvas>
```

and the js that I used to convert simple URL to data URL is :

```
 var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var canvasData = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

What happens over here is that whenever I tries to save my entire canvas element using data:URL, mozilla fiefox give me following error :

```
Security error
[Break On This Error]   
var canvasData = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

I have searched through a number of posts and forums but no one is giving appropriate solution for this.

Passed a lot of time but creating a lot of havoc for me.

Any suggestions will be entertained

Thanxs in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your post and what i found is the same problem that I was facing.

You are getting this error because the images which your application fetches are from live google.play server or from apple store server.

Security is essential whenever we are using canvas. Security is good feature of canvas.

What you are doing is you just fetch the image and resizing and implementing it on canvas.Due to security feature it is not allowing you to manipulate outbound server's image and save it in your DB.

You can use allow-file-access-from-files in console along with firefox.exe command and check it.